# Get log events from all streams

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am using AWS Java SDK.

Is there any way to get log events from Log Group without specifying Log Stream name.

My use case is I want to get VPC Flow Logs , since the Log Streams are created in a dynamic way , it is difficult for me to manage the Log Streams associated with the VPC Flow log, Log Group.

I want some thing where I will specify only Log Group name and get all the  log events from that Log Group.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please post some sample code to login to AWS and read a log event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FilterLogEvents will work for this use case. You can use FilterLogEvents to list all log events from the specified log group as long as the following values are not specified in the request:

- a filter pattern (withFilterPattern)
- a time range (withStartTime, withEndTime)
- one or more log streams (withLogStreamNames)

These values are used to filter the log set, so if you don't want to filter any logs simply don't specify them.

You may need to make use of paging if you intend to retrieve all logs in this group. On the first response you receive back, use [getNextToken()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/logs/model/FilterLogEventsRequest.html#getNextToken--) to set the 'NextToken' in your next request, using [withNextToken()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/logs/model/FilterLogEventsRequest.html#withNextToken-java.lang.String-). Do this for each subsequent request until completion.

**Signature:**

```
public FilterLogEventsResult filterLogEvents(FilterLogEventsRequest filterLogEventsRequest)
```

**Resources:**

- AWS SDK For Java Documentation: [AWS Logs Client - filterLogEvents()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/logs/AWSLogsClient.html#filterLogEvents-com.amazonaws.services.logs.model.FilterLogEventsRequest-)
- Request: [FilterLogEventsRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/logs/model/FilterLogEventsRequest.html)
- Result: [FilterLogEventsResult](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/logs/model/FilterLogEventsResult.html)

Comment: As per this solution data from the first event will be retrieved. What if I want to retrieve data across all the streams in a log group , starting from the specific date?
Can I use the time range parameter here ?

Comment: That's correct. You can specify any permutation of the filter pattern, date range, or log stream names to filter as desired.

Comment: While this works it seems to be impossible to sort events to fetch the latest events first :(